# Twitter Bootstrap - Inline Checkbox Alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Driving myself crazy trying to figure this one out. I can't seem to get the checkboxes that wrap to the next line to left align properly.

Here's some sample code:

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Aaaaaaaaaa
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> Bbbbbbb
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> Cccccccccccccc
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">  
    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Ddddddddd
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> Eeeeeeeee
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> Ffffffffffff
</label>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some context? Where are the labels defined?

Comment: They're just part of the standard bootstrap definitions

Comment: No, I mean are they inside a row-fluid? span? or just in the body?

Comment: Ah, yes in a row-fluid

Comment: Has anyone reported this bug to bootstrap?

Answer (score 49):

You can override the Bootstrap 2 class by adding a no_indent class (or whatever):

```
<label class="checkbox inline no_indent">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Aaaaaaaaaa
</label>
```

and adding this to your CSS:

```
.checkbox.inline.no_indent,
.checkbox.inline.no_indent+.checkbox.inline.no_indent {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.checkbox.inline.no_indent:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

**Bootstrap 3:** The `checkbox inline` classes have been reduced to a single `checkbox-inline` class. The HTML becomes:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Aaaaaaaaaa
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox-inline.no_indent,
.checkbox-inline.no_indent+.checkbox-inline.no_indent {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.checkbox-inline.no_indent:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

**Bootstrap 4:** The `checkbox-inline` class is now `form-check-inline`:

```
<label class="form-check-inline no_indent">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Aaaaaaaaaa
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.form-check-inline.no_indent,
.form-check-inline.no_indent+.checkbox-inline.no_indent {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.form-check-inline.no_indent:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped me too, but isn't the `checkbox-inline.no_indent + .checkbox-inline.no_indent` part redundant ?

Comment: @user1738984 I think there is a corresponding rule that has to be overridden. Its specificity will trump a single declaration. You could always drop it and see what happens.

Comment: For Bootstrap 4.0 beta, `.checkbox-inline` has been changed to `.form-check-inline`.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a complete Bootstrap 3 solution that also fixes the same issue for radio buttons, without having to use a seperate class:

```
.checkbox-inline,
.checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline,
.checkbox-inline + .radio-inline,
.radio-inline,
.radio-inline + .radio-inline,
.radio-inline + .checkbox-inline {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.checkbox-inline:last-child,
.radio-inline:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping each label+input in an `<li>` fixes the margin-left alignment issue with no CSS override/customization

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1"> Option 1
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1"> Option 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This does not solve anything. Where is the ul or ol tag for this?

Comment: just checked this answer and frankly i needed this `<ul> & <li>` pair as i had forgot this pair and was solely stuck in div tags responsiveness in bootstrap... it was not relating to the question above but though it helped me...

Answer (score -3):

Remove `inline` Class on your `label` element.

Comment: Doing so just stacks them on top of each other.  This is not the behavior that was requested.